# How to Georeference 2.5D or Birds Eye View models or Buildings?

Tags: web-mapping, 3d

I am working on 2.5D mapping.So I don't know how to georeference Birds Eye Viewor 2.5D view buildings.If you did not understand then open http://www.youcity.com there you will find 2.5D buildings.If anyone knows help me.

Answer (score 1):

youcity is just normal map tiles rendered but not georeferenced - but complied in Adobe Flex - they have **one** created a 2.5D image
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D

This is true aerial 'bird's eye view' in the correct place (georeferenced)
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/keir.clarke/aerial.htm
plus you can rotate the view for each location.